# Least number of non-zero coefficients to describe a degree n polynomial

Tags: nt.number-theory, polynomials, ag.algebraic-geometry, oeis

I'd be grateful for a good reference on this, it feels like a classic subject yet I couldn't find much about it.

Polynomials in one variable of the form $x^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\dots +a_1 x+a_0$ can be transformed into simpler expressions. For instance [it is apparently well-known](http://homepage.mac.com/ehgoins/ma598/lecture_27.pdf) that the Tschirnhaus transformation allows to bring *any* quintic into so-called Bring-Jerrard form $x^5+ax+b$, while for degree 6 one needs at least three coefficents $x^6+ax^2+bx+c$.

Is there a name for such "generalized Bring-Jerrard form", and what is known about it?   In particular there is a cryptic footnote of Arnold (page 3 of [this lecture](http://www.pdmi.ras.ru/~arnsem/Arnold/arnlect1.ps.gz)) where he says roughly that the degrees for which more coefficients are needed occur along "a rather strange infinite sequence": could someone please describe what those degrees are (I had a look at the OEIS but I believe that sequence is different from [Hamilton numbers](https://oeis.org/A000905), and couldn't find a relevant one).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You might have a look at [Polynomial Transformations of Tschirnhaus, Bring and Jerrard](http://www.apmaths.uwo.ca/~djeffrey/Offprints/Adamchik.pdf) ([Internet Archive](http://web.archive.org/web/20180816061604/http://www.apmaths.uwo.ca/~djeffrey/Offprints/Adamchik.pdf)). It gives more explicit detail on why you can remove the first three terms after the leading term (covering the cases of degree 5 and 6 you mention above), but it does concentrate on degree 5.

Hamilton's [1836 paper](http://www.maths.tcd.ie/pub/HistMath/People/Hamilton/Jerrard/Jerrard.pdf) ([Internet Archive](http://web.archive.org/web/20171126173729/https://www.maths.tcd.ie/pub/HistMath/People/Hamilton/Jerrard/Jerrard.pdf)) on Jerrard's original work has an elementary explanation of the technique (much of the paper concentrates on showing that certain other reductions Jerrard proposed, including a general degree 6 polynomial to a degree 5, were "illusory"). It also explains Jerrard's trick for eliminating the 2nd, 3rd and 5th terms. Finally, Jerrard has a method for eliminating the second and fourth terms, while bringing the third and fifth coefficients into any specified ratio: this only works in degree 7 or above (Jerrard had mistakenly thought this worked generally, and thus solved the general quintic by reducing it to de Moivre's solvable form -- this all predates Abel's work!)

If by "Bring-Jerrard" form you just mean a certain number of the initial terms (after the first) have been eliminated, then the Hamilton numbers you linked to are indeed exactly what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and the references. Right, I was confused, Arnold's footnote really deals with something else, namely the least number of non-zero coefficients of certain equations of degree n whose solutions are universal functions from solving any other equation of the same degree. So Arnold's sequence giving the numbers of those non-zero coefficients for each degree is definitely different from Hamilton's (and probably quite interesting too).

Answer (score 21):

The modern notion of the [essential dimension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Essential_dimension) of a group gives a precise way to state your question (and generalizations), and there is some recent work extending the work mentioned in Scott's answer.  To get started, see the article

[J. Buhler and Z. Reichstein, On the essential dimension of a group, *Compositio Math.* **106** (1997), 159-179.](https://doi.org/10.1023/A:1000144403695)

For instance, it is proved there that for polynomials of degree $n$, at least $\lfloor n/2 \rfloor$ coefficients are required.  (This agrees with what you mentioned for $n=5$ and $n=6$.)

Comment: Thank you very much for this extremely interesting reference!